# master page link's background colour is changing in Internet explorer but not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, firefox

I have one link whose background colour has to change when I click on it. So I have used a JavaScript function to do this,but it is working in Internet explorer but not changing in Mozilla Firefox.

The code is below:

```
function hilite() {
    Trend.style.background= "#000000";
}
```

Here trend is the id of the Link tag.

Link:

```
<a id="Trend" style="color: #FFFFFF;
 text-decoration: none;" href="ATrendAnalysis.aspx">Trend Analysis</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Cs file:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "ScriptRegistration1", "hilite();", true);
```

Comment: Trend.style.background= "#000000"; to document.getElementById('Trend').style.backgroundColor = '#000000';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```
 Trend.style.background= "#000000";
```

"Trend" is a JavaScript variable, which is not defined. This is NOT referencing an element in the DOM.

Use:

```
document.getElementById('Trend').style.background= "#000000";
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to apply some styles to the link using CSS by using the pseudo-class selector :active.

:Active would apply the defined style (in your case, it would be change its background color) only while the link is being pressed.